# How to use bash to find a line given a pattern to comment out

Tags: bash, ubuntu

My /etc/hosts looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1      test test
```

I need to use bash to find "127.0.1.1" and comment the line out so the file looks like this:

```
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  #127.0.1.1      test test
```

Ho to I do that with a command line one liner on ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through sed,

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/^127\.0\.1\.1/s/^/#/' /etc/hosts
```

In Ubuntu, to edit `/etc/hosts` file, you need superuser do permission, so i added `sudo` before the sed command. And the sed's in-line edit option `-i` allows you to save the changes made to that file. `-i.bak` creates a backup  for `/etc/hosts` on the `/etc` directory itself before performing the operation.

Comment: It is always good to make a backup, much more if it is sensitive files like this. Hence, `-i.bak.{date}` would be best.

Comment: Well with `{date}` I meant something like `$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M")`... :D